# linq subtracts number in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I subtract numbers in a list in query?

```cs
var q = lists.Select(v => new LegalSuitReport
{
    CargoQtystr= v.Claim.ClaimBLs.Select(qq => qq.JobBL.CargoQty).ToList(),
    RecipetedQtystr = v.Claim.ClaimBLs.Select(qq => qq.JobBL.LandedQty).ToList()
    diff= v.Claim.ClaimBLs.Select(qq => qq.JobBL.CargoQtystr) - v.Claim.ClaimBLs.Select(qq => qq.JobBL.LandedQty)

}).ToList().Select(qs => new LegalSuitReport()
{
    CargoQty= string.Join(",", qs.CargoQtystr),
    RecipetedQty = string.Join(",", qs.RecipetedQtystr)
    diff = string.Join(",", qs.RecipetedQtystr)

}).ToList();
```

I want to subtract numbers with same indexes in these cargoqty and receiptedqty and have there difference between in diff

```
List<decimal> cargoqty= new List<decimal>{500,100000,150};
List<decimal> RecipetedQtystr = new List<decimal>{5,90000,15};
List<decimal> diff= new List<decimal>{495,10000,135};
```

Comment: Could you share, sample input and excepted output.

Comment: There is no need to use `ToList()` at the middle

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt to "subtract". From the samples it looks like  `Zip()` would helps

Comment: There is no need to use ToList() at the middle =>please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

From the samples, it looks like [Zip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) would help:

```
var diff=cargoqty.Zip(RecipetedQtystr,(q1,q2)=>q1-q2).ToList();
```

`Zip` combines two sequences in pairs. This particular overload applies a function to the pairs before returning the result